# How can I create a user for ASP.Net/Umbraco SQL Membership from iPhone and WCF?

Tags: iphone, wcf, asp.net-membership, umbraco, sqlmembershipprovider

So I have been struggling for days now, trying to simply create a new user with a WCF Service using Umbraco's Membership Provider. Can someone tell me if I'm out of my mind, if this is impossible to do, or if I'm overlooking something I need to add to my WCF Service to allow this to work. My WCF script is embedded into my website on IIS 7.5 using .NET Framework 4.0.

I can currently return my JSON strings from WCF, such as validation of input. And I will be using this from an iPhone App.

But as soon as everything validates, and I try to run the following lines...

```
  MembershipCreateStatus status;    
  MembershipUser newUser = Membership.CreateUser(email, pw1, email, "n", "n", false, out status);

  if (newUser != null)
  {
    string newUserGuid = System.Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N");
    MemberProfile mp = MemberProfile.GetUserProfile(email);
    mp.AuthGuid = newUserGuid;
    mp.FirstName = fname;
    mp.LastName = lname;
    mp.Birthday = bDay;
    mp.DisplayRealName = intName;
    mp.DisplayBirthday = intBirthday;
    mp.Save();
    Roles.AddUserToRole(email, "Client");
    return @"Valid:User Added";
  }else
    return @"Error:Invalid:Error Occurred";
  }
```

I get the following error...

> The server encountered an error processing the request. The exception message is 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'. See server logs for more details. The exception stack trace is:
>
> at
>   umbraco.cms.businesslogic.member.Member.GetMemberFromLoginName(String
>   loginName) at
>   umbraco.providers.members.UmbracoMembershipProvider.CreateUser(String
>   username, String password, String
>   email, String passwordQuestion, String
>   passwordAnswer, Boolean isApproved,
>   Object providerUserKey,
>   MembershipCreateStatus& status) at
>   System.Web.Security.Membership.CreateUser(String
>   username, String password, String
>   email, String passwordQuestion, String
>   passwordAnswer, Boolean isApproved,
>   Object providerUserKey,
>   MembershipCreateStatus& status) at
>   System.Web.Security.Membership.CreateUser(String
>   username, String password, String
>   email, String passwordQuestion, String
>   passwordAnswer, Boolean isApproved,
>   MembershipCreateStatus& status) at
>   MyDll.Web.AUsers.RegisterUser(String
>   email, String pw1, String pw2, String
>   fname, String lname, Int32 intName,
>   String birthdate, Int32 intBirthday)
>   at MyDll.Web.get.Users.Register(String
>   email, String p1, String p2, String
>   fname, String lname, String
>   displayname, String birthdate, String
>   displaybirth) at
>   SyncInvokeRegister(Object , Object[] ,
>   Object[] ) at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.SyncMethodInvoker.Invoke(Object
>   instance, Object[] inputs, Object[]&
>   outputs) at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.InvokeBegin(MessageRpc&
>   rpc) at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage5(MessageRpc&
>   rpc) at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage41(MessageRpc&
>   rpc) at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage4(MessageRpc&
>   rpc) at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage31(MessageRpc&
>   rpc) at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage3(MessageRpc&
>   rpc) at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage2(MessageRpc&
>   rpc) at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage11(MessageRpc&
>   rpc) at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage1(MessageRpc&
>   rpc) at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc.Process(Boolean
>   isOperationContextSet)

My Web Config section looks like this...

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <webHttpBinding>
        <binding name="jsonBinding" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
          <security mode="Transport">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </webHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <services>
      <service name="MyDll.Users">
        <endpoint address="/get/Users.svc" behaviorConfiguration="jsonBehavior"
          binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="jsonBinding"
          name="UsersService" contract="MyDll.Web.get.Users" />
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="jsonBehavior">
          <enableWebScript />
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment
      multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Any help whatesoever would be GREATLY appreciated. And if I could buy you a beer or 10, I would.
Thanks!

Comment: ok, so i've narrowed it down to the following cause of the error...

`code` Membership.CreateUser(email, pw1, email, "n", "n", false, out status);`code` 

 but its still not working :(

and i removed, `code`MembershipUser newUser = `code`, so now i just rely on `code` MembershipCreateStatus status;`code` to determine if it was successful or not.

Comment: Everyone, I'm on to something here...I dont think what I want to do above is possible, without 509 certs and all that junk. I'm actually writing the code and stored procedure to take care of this whole membership insert into Umbraco for me. Will keep everyone posted on my findings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In umbraco Member.cs, there is

```
HttpContext.Current.Trace.Warn("No member with loginname: " + loginName + " Exists");
```

So you got such error.

In web.config under system.serviceModel add:

```
<serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled=”true”/>
```

on your service class

```
[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Required)]
```

For more information, please see
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa702682.aspx

http://our.umbraco.org/forum/developers/api-questions/18465-Access-Umbraco-Content-from-WCF-Service